# Listview/ExpandableListView image content flick when call notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

The Listview/ExpandableListView will constantly update and there will be new entry in and out. and each row contain imageview and text.

when i call `notifyDataSetChanged`, the random row's imageview will flick.
I understand that cause of the view is refresh from top to bottom. But is there any way to update the content without refresh the whole list or anyway to make the imageview not flick?

I did try `Invalidate()` as well, but it is not what i want.

Is there any way to customize listview/ExpandableListView to use?

Answer (score 0):

One thing can be done,

1.get all the child view currently on screen    this may help you-[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001760/android-listview-get-data-index-of-visible-item/2002413#2002413](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724874/how-can-i-update-a-single-row-in-a-listview)

2.then in each child first update the array then view that need to update, not the image
  [How can I update a single row in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724874/how-can-i-update-a-single-row-in-a-listview)

i hope this can help you.

Thank you.