# Android load only visible elements of ListView

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading, visible

I'm using Lazy Loading List in my application and I need to load only the visible elements of ListView.I've search over the internet,tried a lot of things but still cannot get the things to work.Can you give me a suggestion how to do it?

Here is the ImageLoader class :

```
package com.stampii.stampii.tableview;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import com.stampii.stampii.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {

    //the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    private File cacheDir;
    private AssetManager mAssetManager;


    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);
        mAssetManager = context.getAssets();

        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Stampii");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }


    final int stub_id=R.drawable.default_img;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        if(cache.containsKey(url))
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }    
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)  //opashka
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String src) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = null;


                //Decryption
                try {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
                SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec("01234567890abcde".getBytes(), "AES");
                IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec("fedcba9876543210".getBytes());
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

                InputStream input = mAssetManager.open(src);
                CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(input, cipher);

                myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cis);

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("ERROR","Error : "+e);
                }


                return myBitmap;


        }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        Object tag=photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
                        if(tag!=null && ((String)tag).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        //clear memory cache

        long size=0;
            cache.clear();

            //clear SD cache
            File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
            for(File f:files){
                size=size+f.length();
                    f.delete();
            }
    }




}
```

**EDIT1:**

getView method in my LazyAdapter class :

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.name=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.info=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.info);
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        holder.name.setText("MotoGP Rider");
        holder.info.setText("Category");
        holder.image.setTag(data[position]);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, holder.image);
        return vi;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the code: I am sure that ONLY the images that are visible are being loaded!

BUT because some of the images down have the same url! You will think that they are loading in a different order. However they are loaded based on the images visible but any other listitem with the same url will show the image.

---

> I'm using Lazy Loading List in my application and I need to load only the visible elements of ListView.

`getView` is called for each position that is visible on the ListView

The pictures you need to load must be added to the queue from the `getView` of the Adapter

So you should Override

```
public View   getView  (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    super(position,convertView,parent);
    //now add the picture at position to the queue
}
```

***Note: Be careful***

Say you added photo 1 to the queue: This **does not mean** that `getView` will not be called again with position 1.

In other words, account for the fact that a position may be called many times using `getView`.

Comment: I just update my code with the getView that I'm using...and didn not understand everything that you said..

Comment: In all your code: `DisplayImage` and `queuePhoto` Are they called somewhere else?

Comment: Only in ImageLoader.class and in the getView method.

Comment: No I mean is it only called in `getView`

Comment: Okay So this only loads the views that are visible!

Comment: I want to load the images which are visible on the screen.Example: I have 120 items in listview, but when I start the activity I can see only 15 of them.And I want to load only these 15 whe the activity start.And when I'm scrolling down to start loading the other images,which are visible.

Comment: @Bombastic let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2461/discussion-between-sherif-and-bombastic)

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand that dude!

Answer (score 0):

To load only visible elements you need to implements a interface of AbsListView.OnScrollListener. From this interface you can find out the "scroll event" and "scrolleventstate" change from its methods.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, items);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, 
        int scrollState) {
     // Do nothing
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, 
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    // threshold being indicator if bottom of list is hit
    if (firstVisibleItem = threshold) {
        pullMoreData();
    }
}
});
```

For more explanation about this. you can follow this tutorials. [smart loading listview](https://devblog.xing.com/mobile/smart-loading-of-images-in-android-app-contact-lists/), [dynamic data listview](https://chrisarriola.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/dynamic-data-with-listview-loading-footer/), [detect end scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358428/implementation-of-onscrolllistener-to-detect-the-end-of-scrolling-in-a-listview), [get visible data index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001760/android-listview-get-data-index-of-visible-item)