# GridView Get Item On Touch

Tags: java, android, grid

I'm trying to get the item selected when i touch a gridview, i cant use the onClick as that starts another activity. What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to move items in a gridview around and since i cant find a way of doing it I'm trying to make a way..

So yeah.. Is there a way to get which item has been 'touched', I've tried using a Rect and it hasn't worked properly..

(Can i just elaborate.. i Cant use the onItemClick for this..)

Any help would be great, Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  You want to determine which item has been clicked so you can move it, but you can't use the method that's called when an item is clicked because a new Activity is launched?  If you want a feature such as is used on Android homescreens, you could look into the onLongClickListener().

Comment: Hello Thomas, Can you please share some code snippet as I have to solve similar kind of problem where I want to arrange the images of a grid from one cell to another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Glendon Trullinger's suggestion of using onLongClickListener isn't sufficient for you, try [GridView#pointToPosition(int x, int y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#pointToPosition(int,%20int)), which you can call from a `View.OnTouchListener`, using the `MotionEvent`'s x and y coordinates.  With that position, you can get the child view at that position using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257514/android-access-child-views-from-a-listview/2679284#2679284), and/or you can get the adapter item itself using [AdapterView#getItemAtPosition(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition(int))

Answer (score 19):

To get the item that was 'touched'

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

            int action = me.getActionMasked();  // MotionEvent types such as ACTION_UP, ACTION_DOWN
            float currentXPosition = me.getX();
            float currentYPosition = me.getY();
            int position = gridView.pointToPosition((int) currentXPosition, (int) currentYPosition);

            // Access text in the cell, or the object itself
            String s = (String) gridView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            TextView tv = (TextView) gridView.getChildAt(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not simple nor elegant. gridView.getChildAt(position) will return null because the GridView reuses it's elements, like ListView does with the rows.