# android change view of selected item in adapterview

Tags: android, listview, android-adapterview, itemselector

I have a listview with a textview as each item. I want to change the textcolor of the selected item. For this use the `onItemSelected` method to make the changes. Say first I select the 1st row, the first row's textcolor changes. Now when I select the 2nd row, its text color also changes, but I want the 1st row's color to change back to its default color. How do I do that, since in the `onItemSelected` I only get the refernce of the currently selected item and not the last selected. Is there any way other than holding a reference to the last selected view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When first item is selected store its position in instance variable of your activity, lets name it `currentlySelected`. Then combine with this [Android: Access child views from a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257514/android-access-child-views-from-a-listview)
in order to get the view at position `currentlySelected` and change it's textcolor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in Java, you can let android handles it in the xml file. See [Color State List Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).