# Prevent ListView from destroying objects off-screen

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm [trying to get data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293340/getting-data-from-simpleadapter) stored in parts of a ListView. However, when a View scrolls off the page, the View is destroyed.

How do I tell the ListView not to destroy content that goes off screen?

Comment: That's how it works and for memory management. If u dont want that then you might have to go for ScrollView which will lead you to memory issues soon

Comment: Sometimes you want the efficient method. Sometimes you want to keep all of it. It would be nice to quickly toggle.

Comment: You can always access the data from a listview from his adapter. The objects from adapter are not destroyed when the view is recycled.

Comment: @UngureanuLiviu If you know a way to access the data from the adapter without taking it from ListView, I would be grateful if you could answer the linked question :)

Comment: :) No, I don't know such a I way but I was thinking about (MyObjectFromAdapter)mylistview.getAdapter().getItem(position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a view to be destroyed in your Listview you need to change to a Scrollview instead of a Listview.
The whole point of a Listview is to display a lot of data efficiently.