# How to know which row in an android listview a button was pressed in?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListActivity and In my list I have highly complex listitems with multiple ImagesViews TextViews, and Buttons.  When I click a button i want to edit some of the textviews and change some background colors.  My implementation works but only if the button that I click is within the first row visible.  I'm using `getChildAt()` to grab one of the visible rows but I need to know which one to grab.

```
public void onClick(View v){
    System.out.println("Something got clicked");
    if(v.getId() == R.id.lovebutton){
        MainListItem i = mainAdapter.getItem(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
            i.loved=true;
            i.loves++;
            View view;
                view = listView.getChildAt(0);
                //view = listView.getChildAt(1);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lovecount)).setText(String.valueOf(i.loves));
            view.findViewById(R.id.lovebutton).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(i.brandLoveColor));
            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.lovebutton)).setImageResource(R.drawable.lovewhite);
        }}
```

Comment: why don't you use BaseAdapter and handle each view separately....?

Comment: what are the differences between ArrayAdapter and BaseAdapter? I'm currently using ArrayAdapter

Comment: is the button part of the ListView?

Comment: Is this code is of your adapter class or activity? Can you post some more code ?

Comment: @mpatten ArrayAdapter is subclass of baseadapter

Comment: this is part of the onClick method defined in the ListActivity class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways in which you can do this. Saving the states in the pojo, updating them in onClick and calling `#notifyDataSetChanged()`. 
Alternatively,
You can add the position as a tag to the button in getView of the adapter. In OnClick you can get the tag. This way you will know which position the button belongs to.

With a little help from Joe - [Android: Access child views from a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257514/android-access-child-views-from-a-listview)

```
public void onClick(View v){
    System.out.println("Something got clicked");
    if(v.getId() == R.id.lovebutton){
        int wantedPosition = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag());
        int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() - listView.getHeaderViewsCount(); // This is the same as child #0
        int wantedChild = wantedPosition - firstPosition;
        // Say, first visible position is 8, you want position 10, wantedChild will now be 2
        // So that means your view is child #2 in the ViewGroup:
        if (wantedChild < 0 || wantedChild >= listView.getChildCount()) {
          Log.w(TAG, "Unable to get view for desired position, because it's not being displayed on screen.");
          return;
        }
        // Could also check if wantedPosition is between listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() and listView.getLastVisiblePosition() instead.
        View wantedView = listView.getChildAt(wantedChild);
        MainListItem i = mainAdapter.getItem(wantedPosition);
        i.loved=true;
        i.loves++;
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lovecount)).setText(String.valueOf(i.loves));
        view.findViewById(R.id.lovebutton).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(i.brandLoveColor));
        ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.lovebutton)).setImageResource(R.drawable.lovewhite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up using the `setTag()` on the button and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

In a listView to get the clicked row , You have to use "OnItemClickListener".

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int pos, long arg3) {
                        HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(pos);    
                          System.out.println(pos);//This will return your position

                    }
                });
```