# Get value from textview in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

I'm following this guide to create a listview with textviews and eddittexts in it. 
http://www.webplusandroid.com/creating-listview-with-edittext-and-textwatcher-in-android/
When I try to get values from listview items, I get only textviews values. It seems impossible getting text from the edittext based on listview position. 
I use `lv.getItemAtPosition(0).toString())` to retrieve values

Comment: Please post how you are getting TextViews result.

Comment: add your code plz

Comment: I added my code, the rest of the code with explanation is on the link

Comment: The linked post uses an Adapter... Why are you trying to access the views from the ListView itself?

Comment: You possibly could follow this post, then maybe use `findViewById`, for example, on the row view to get the correct view.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257514/android-access-child-views-from-a-listview

Comment: In this way I'm getting the correct view, but I still can't receive EditText's text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following: [Android: Access child views from a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257514/android-access-child-views-from-a-listview)

```
int wantedChild = 1;
View wantedView = listview.getChildAt(wantedChild);
mEditText = (EditText) wantedView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
Log.d("result",(mEditText.getText().toString()));
```